# Javascript call to a SignalR hub method doesn't return a value

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, signalr

I am writing a chat room page for my web site, and I've run into a bit of a snag.  I want to be sure that the names being used by chat room participants are unique.  The hub class itself contains a List<> of participants already taking part in the chat, so I added a method to the class to check for the existence of a name already in use:

```
    public bool UserNameInUse(string name)
    {
        UserDetail item = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserName == name);
        return (item.ConnectionId == null);
    }
```

On the Javascript side, I am trying to call the hub method to check if the name is already in use before starting the connection, like so:

```
   $("#btnStartChat").click(function () {

    var name = $("#txtNickName").val();
    if (name.length > 0) {
        var status = chatHub.server.userNameInUse(name);
        alert(status);
        if (status!=1)
            chatHub.server.connect(name);
        else
            alert("The name you chose is already in use.  Try a different one, please.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Please enter a name to use for this chat.");
    }
});
```

As you can see, I instrumented the call to see what was being returned.  But rather than obtaining a value from the hub method call 
(which *does* fire, since I tested it in Visual Studio under debug mode), this is what I get from the alert box:

[image: screenshot of what the call returns]

I've tried changing the return type to a string and sending back text, to an int and returning a number, yet I get the same result every time when I run the code.  Can anyone help me understand why the call doesn't return a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register callback functions to receive the server response e.g.

```
chatHub.server.UserNameInUse(name).done(function (isInUse) {
    if (isInUse) {
       // Server returned true
    } else {
       // Server returned false
    }
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.log('Invocation of UserNameInUsefailed. Error: ' + error);
});
```

For more info check out the SignalR docs here

[How to call server methods from the client](https://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#callserver)

Comment: Worked very nicely.  Thank you!